# Staged_predict from a Pipeline object

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am having the same issue which was outlined years ago here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10197

It seems to not have been resolved so I am looking for a work around. The example given there no longer works so here is one I wrote based on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_partial_dependence.html

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from time import time
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingRegressor

bikes = fetch_openml("Bike_Sharing_Demand", version=2, as_frame=True, parser="pandas")
# Make an explicit copy to avoid "SettingWithCopyWarning" from pandas
X, y = bikes.data.copy(), bikes.target

X["weather"].replace(to_replace="heavy_rain", value="rain", inplace=True)

mask_training = X["year"] == 0.0
X = X.drop(columns=["year"])
X_train, y_train = X[mask_training], y[mask_training]
X_test, y_test = X[~mask_training], y[~mask_training]

numerical_features = [
    "temp",
    "feel_temp",
    "humidity",
    "windspeed",
]
categorical_features = X_train.columns.drop(numerical_features)

hgbdt_preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("cat", OrdinalEncoder(), categorical_features),
        ("num", "passthrough", numerical_features),
    ],
    sparse_threshold=1,
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
).set_output(transform="pandas")



hgbdt_model = make_pipeline(
    hgbdt_preprocessor,
    HistGradientBoostingRegressor(
        categorical_features=categorical_features, random_state=0
    ),
)
hgbdt_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

staged_predict_train = [i for i in hgbdt_model.staged_predict(X_train)]
```

This produces AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'staged_predict'

The first thing I tried was to just pass it directly to the model in the pipeline

```
staged_predict_train = [i for i in hgbdt_model['histgradientboostingregressor'].staged_predict(X_train)]
```

This fails because X_train is no longer encoded by the prior step in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to get columntransformer to transform the columns

```
enc = clf['columntransformer']
X_train_encoded = enc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_encoded = enc.fit_transform(X_test)

staged_predict_train = [i.transpose()[1] for i in clf['histgradientboostingclassifier'].staged_predict_proba(X_train_encoded)]
```